# Installing a python module when more than one version of python is installed on the system

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

So here's the situation. We have a server running Scientific Linux 5.5 and the newest version of python in the base repos is 2.4. I really need a newer version and I discovered that python 2.6 could be installed via yum as python26 from the EPEL repos.

I also need the python libraries numpy and matplotlib to be available to the python26 install. Python26-numpy is available in the EPEL repo but there isn't a python26 version of matplotlib available.

To summarize:
python 2.4 installed with numpy and matplotlib form base repos (but I need newer versions)
python 2.6 installed with numpy as python26 from EPEL repos, BUT matplotlib unavailable.

I assume there must be a way to manual install matplotlib such that it can be accessed by the python26 install, but I'm not sure what the proper/best way to go about doing it is and I don't want to skrew anything up on this server since my whole group uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to install `virtualenv` (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and then install all the packages you need (including `numpy` and `matplotlib`) inside of that `virtualenv`. Then, you would run your code inside that `virtualenv`, and it would not affect anyone else nor the base `Python` install.

(The only thing you would need to install in the base Python installer would be `pip` and `virtualenv` if they are not already present).

Others in your group could then also create their own `virtualenv`'s for their needs, containing various other packages, and not overlap with each other.

The environment can also be stored in a **requirements** file via the output from `pip freeze` and checked into `source control`, and then used to re-create the same `virtualenv` elsewhere (useful for situations such as use with `Jenkins`, test environments, etc.).

Comment: For others who find this answer, this website was very helpful: http://dubroy.com/blog/so-you-want-to-install-a-python-package/